# How to know with Ruby if a path is outside another?

Tags: ruby, file, directory, dir

I'm building a little script and I'd need to know some way of testing if a path (a string for example) is outside another path (another string). For example:

`/some/path` and `/some/path/file.rb` would return `false` because `file.rb` is inside `/some/path` but `/some/path` and `/some/file.rb` would return `true` because `file.rb` it's outside `/some/path`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`String#starts_with?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-start_with-3F):

```
path = '/some/path'
file = '/some/path/file.rb'
file.starts_with?(path) #=> true
```

And:

```
path = '/some/path'
file = '/some/file.rb'
file.starts_with?(path) #=> false
```